# what is the linux command for a root to delete a folder from home directory of any user

Tags: linux, fedora

Hi I am using Fedora 10. I am using as root. I have 3 users and there is a folder named "data" in the home directory of 2 users out of 3. I want to delete those folders.

What is the command to delete a folder from home directories of all users.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 7):

To be fully pedantic you should probably use *getent* instead of looking at /etc/passwd, just in case you have users form other sources such as NIS, SQL, LDAP, etc. To get the list of homedirectories you could use this:

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f6
```

And to delete all data directories for all users:

```
for home in $(getent passwd | cut -d: -f6) ; do
    if [ -d "$home/data" ]; then
        rm -rf "$home/data"
    fi
done
```

The extra *if* statement is there to make sure you do not accidentally delete files.

Answer (score 2):

First, check what is going to be deleted (as suggested by David, I should have mention that, I'd never run the next command blindly):

```
ls -al /home/*/data
```

And, if nothing is wrong, perform the delete:

```
rm -rf /home/*/data
```

Comment: yes, he wants to delete from only 2 out of the 3 users

Comment: Are you sure? I'd like the OP to answer.

Comment: Sounds to me like only 2 of the 3 users have the folder.  I think this should work just fine, though I'd want to be doubly sure before I ran it.

Comment: And I'd do `ls -l /home/*/data` first to see exactly what I was going to delete.

Answer (score 2):

assuming the home directories are in /home, you would do this:

```
for user in 'user1' 'user2'
do
rm -rf /home/$user/data
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply delete the folder in several user accounts in one step, you can use

```
# rm -rf /path/to/home/(user1|user2|user3|...)/data
```

Note that this only deletes the folder and not the user.  For every user, You'll need a quick Awk command such as

```
$ grep "/home" /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{ print $1 }'
```

To get a listing.  The problem with the awk command is that it doesn't know the difference between a system user that doesn't have a home directory and one that does.

Comment: Except that parentheses and pipes don't work in this context unless you're using zsh. For bash and ksh, use: `{user1,user2,user3,...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
# cd /home/
# find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -iname data -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The **find** command is useful in this context because it is automatically recursive, won't accidentally delete a file by the same name and will scale better than most solutions to this type of problem (with the exception of the old "too many arguments" issue bumped into by experienced sysadmins - see **xargs** for that).

A quick rundown of the meaning of *this* specific **find** command:

- maxdepth: do not descend beyond one directory below that given on the command line (.);
- type: only find directories
- iname: case-insensitive match on the name against the string "data"
- exec: command to execute against matching objects found - in this case, rm -rf
- {}: placeholder for each matching object found
- \;: the semi-colon used to end each command is escaped to stop shell expansion

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could stick a `-mindepth` in there, too, in case Brent Spiner is a user of your system.